# SQL Select Query not showing data in the statement

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a very simple table that links ITEM numbers to GL Codes, I am running into a problem with my SQL Query not showing me every ITEM number in my statement

Here is my table

```
ITEM    ITEM_NAME   GL Code
18004       Banana Green Tip    4500-03-10
62080       Pineapple Costa Rican Gold  4500-14-10
80089       Broccoli Floret Bite Size   5000-03-10
98010       Carrot Jumbo Tx/mex/mich    5000-04-10
101335      Popcorn Cheddar White Lss   5000-04-10
105068      Spinach Baby    4500-02-10
105615      Mayonnaise Pc Hellmans Real 4500-03-10
106048      Tortilla Flour Casera 6 In  4500-14-10
106188      Egg Patty Homestyle Fried   5000-03-10
109001      Cucumber Large English 12 Ct    5000-04-10
110179      Bread Knot Garlic 1.3 Oz    4500-02-10
111001      Eggplant #1 18/24 Ct    4500-03-10
111423      Creamer Half & Half Pc  4500-14-10
111699      Bean Pinto Fancy    5000-03-10
114293      Quinoa Tri-color Prewashed  5000-04-10
115800      Ice Cream Cup Choc Fat Free 4500-02-10
116421      Ice Cream Bar Snickers  4500-03-10
171110      Foil Sheet 10.75 X 9 In 4500-14-10
117566      Cantaloupe 12 Ct    5000-03-10
117569      Honeydew Melon 6 Ct 5000-04-10
119825      Milk 2% Reduced Fat 1/2 Pt  4500-02-10
119826      Milk Homo Vitamin D 1/2 Pt  4500-03-10
120564      Egg Liquid Ez Breakfast Blend   4500-14-10
121935      Gravy Mix Peppered  5000-03-10
126052      Lettuce Romaine Chopped K   5000-04-10
127922      Turkey Sliced .7oz Oven Rstd    4500-02-10
128656      Cont Plas Hngd 3-c Black Clear  4500-03-10
129226      Brussels Sprouts Halves 4500-14-10
133410      Chicken Breast Blsl 6oz Iqf 5000-03-10
136615      Wipe Sanitizer Norinse Canistr  5000-04-10
139371      Cheese Pepper Jack 120 Slice    4500-02-10
140297      Plate Square Fiber 8x8  4500-03-10
142730      Pancake Buttermilk  4500-14-10
143578      Sauce Pc Bbq Hickory Brn Sugar  5000-03-10
146968      Ketchup Individual 9 Gram Pc    5000-04-10
146990      Sausage Chorizo Bulk Tub    4500-02-10
148802      Dough Cookie Choc Chip  4500-03-10
148803      Dough Cookie Dbl Choc   4500-14-10
150105      Onion Green Iceless 5000-03-10
151009      Onion Red Jumbo Us#1    5000-04-10
151499      Cheese Cheddar Slice Mild   4500-02-10
153502      Ketchup Upside Down Squeeze 4500-03-10
154855      Fuel Chafing Gel 2 Hr   4500-14-10
155030      Onion Yellow Jumbo  5000-03-10
160386      Ice Cream Bar Big Bopper    5000-04-10
168466      Chip Potato Variety 4500-02-10
168551      Salsa Verde Roasted 4500-03-10
170213      Cheese Provolone Slice  4500-14-10
171082      Ice Cream Bar Bomb Pop Jr   5000-03-10
171143      Cheese Cheddar Shred Feather    5000-04-10
172686      Bacon Applewood Layout 14/18    4500-02-10
178140      Strawberry Clamshell 1 Lb   4500-03-10
178755      Salad Mix Arcadian Classic  4500-14-10
179181      Chip Variety Classic    5000-03-10
284272      Milk Chocolate Whole 1/2 Pt  K  5000-04-10
285136      Cream Heavy Whipping 36%    4500-02-10
285555      Ice Cream Bar Twin Pops 4500-03-10
286475      Ice Cream Bar Big Alaska    4500-14-10
288620      Ice Cream Bar Heath 5000-03-10
338309      Corn Cob 3 Inch 5000-04-10
338603      Corn Cut Super Sweet    4500-02-10
349245      Vegetable Blend California  4500-03-10
349452      Vegetable Blend Oriental    4500-14-10
353113      French Fries Sc 3/8 In Skin On  5000-03-10
358015      Potato Breakfast Cube Skin On   5000-04-10
362160      Potato Sliced Natural Smooth    4500-02-10
384488      Pizza Cheese Round 5 In 4500-03-10
384528      Pizza Pepperoni 5 In Iw 4500-14-10
389018      Butter Solid Unsalted   5000-03-10
393795      Egg Omelette W/cheddar Chs  5000-04-10
394337      Bread Wheatberry 1/2 In Sl  4500-02-10
394439      Bread French Baguette   4500-03-10
394571      Bread Texas Toast White 4500-14-10
398683      Roll Assorted Banquet   5000-03-10
398787      Bagel Variety Unsliced 4oz  5000-04-10
401166      Waffle Belgian 4 Inch   4500-02-10
407517      Muffin English Presliced 4 Oz   4500-03-10
408169      Tortilla Corn White 4.5 Inch    4500-14-10
413331      Cake Coffee Pullman Asst Sl 5000-03-10
414386      Cake Coconut Sheet W/icing  5000-04-10
414391      Cake Orange Sheet With Icing    4500-02-10
414431      Cake Carrot Sheet Iced  4500-03-10
414754      Cake Sheet Red Velvet Iced  4500-14-10
415120      Cheesecake French Cream 8x15    5000-03-10
455784      Tilapia Fillet Tortilla Crust   5000-04-10
483882      Sauce Hollandaise Poly Bag  4500-02-10
487130      Chicken Tender Brd Homestyle    4500-03-10
487926      Chicken 8 Pc Breaded Cooked 4500-14-10
506345      Beef Patty 3/1 Chuck 80/20  5000-04-10
512161      Beef Tip Tenderloin 5000-03-10
522428      Meatball Italian 2 Oz Cooked    4500-02-10
538306      Ham Sliced Smoked .5 Oz 4500-03-10
541344      Sausage Smoked Beef Link 5/1    4500-14-10
550091      Chicken Leg Quarter Random  5000-03-10
550108      Chicken Breast Random Blsl  5000-04-10
550235      Chicken Thigh Meat Blsl 3-6 Oz  4500-02-10
620009      Juice Apple 100%    4500-03-10
620022      Juice Cranberry Cocktail 27%    4500-14-10
620135      Juice Orange 100%   5000-03-10
620354      Juice Grapefruit Ruby Red   5000-04-10
630350      Soda Big Red    4500-02-10
630521      Soda Coke Zero  4500-03-10
630843      Soda Sprite Zero    4500-14-10
639067      Creamer Pc Liq French Vanilla   5000-03-10
639100      Soda Sprite Cube Pack   5000-04-10
639133      Soda Dr Pepper Cube Pack    4500-02-10
650085      Bean Ranch Style Fancy  4500-03-10
650104      Bean Black Fancy    4500-14-10
650322      Potato Mashed Creamy Deluxe 5000-03-10
654008      Rice Long Grain Adolphus    5000-04-10
654084      Rice Brown Long Grain   4500-02-10
660292      Sauce Alfredo Pouch 4500-03-10
661016      Sauce Chili Sweet For Chicken   4500-14-10
674651      Dressing Pc Original Ranch  5000-03-10
674658      Dressing Pc Italian Fat Free    5000-04-10
677255      Syrup Pc Pancake Cup    4500-02-10
699279      Chip Cheeto Hot Limon Lss   4500-03-10
699280      Chip Funyun Lss Gluten Free 4500-14-10
699293      Chip Cheeto Crunchy Hot Lss 5000-03-10
747050      Cheese Mozz Regular Shred   5000-04-10
760014      Cheese Swiss Slice W/holes  4500-02-10
761004      Cheese Velveeta Loaf    4500-03-10
772030      Cookie Oreo Individual 2 Count  4500-14-10
779192      Shortening Mel Fry Liq Orig 5000-03-10
782054      Bean Refried Seasoned   5000-04-10
783216      Tuna Chunk White Albacore   4500-02-10
799047      Cereal Cup Assorted 8 Var   4500-03-10
799199      Cereal Oatmeal Old Fashioned    4500-14-10
871032      Cutlery Knife Black Ex Hw   5000-04-10
885915      Sanitizer Redi-san Rtu  4500-02-10
886054      Sanitizer Tablet    4500-03-10
654081      Rice Wild   4500-14-10
799419      Cereal Grits Instant    5000-03-10
530952      Bacon Canadian Style W/sirloin  5000-04-10
349494      Vegetable Blend Monaco  4500-02-10

SELECT * 
FROM BEK_DelRio 
Where ITEM IN (18004,62080,80089,349494,18004,80089,62080)
```

In my statement I have multiple ITEM Numbers but it will only show the results for that specific ID once

```
ITEM    ITEM_NAME   GL Code
18004       Banana Green Tip    4500-03-10
62080       Pineapple Costa Rican Gold  4500-14-10
80089       Broccoli Floret Bite Size   5000-03-10
349494      Vegetable Blend Monaco  4500-02-10
```

the statement only returns 4 values even though there are 7 IDs in the statement

How do I pull those results for every ID even if the ID is in the statement multiple times?

Comment: Please tag exactly one RDBMS, and add sample data and desired results to your question.

Comment: I included my desired results as a question in the topic 

How do I pull those results for every ID even if the ID is in the statement multiple times?

Comment: And what about the source data?

Comment: included the entire table

Comment: But you have only four _distinct_ item numbers. Why are you expecting more rows?

Comment: I run the SQL query based off the item numbers in the invoice, the invoice has multiple line items with the same ITEM# (18004 for example will be on the invoice 4 times as separate line items)

I thought the argument was solid and the SQL query will show me all items that match that ITEM# regardless of duplicates)

Comment: But there aren't any rows with the same item number in the data you posted.

Comment: Okay thanks i guess i will duplicate my Database 5 times over to get the desired outcome

Comment: Im new to SQL and i assumed that even though the ID is unique but my argument has the same ID multiple times that it would still pull that data anyway.

Comment: I suspect what you want is to join your `invoice` table to the `items` table.

Comment: I just want values to be returned when I query the database even if the IDs arent unique. ID 0004 has a vlaue of 4500 and i want to see that 6 times if I include 0004 6 times in my query but i guess SQL doesnt do that

Comment: check this out: 
[help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to see that 6 times if I include 0004 6 times in my query but i guess SQL doesnt do that

Correct. The `WHERE` clause filters your table down to only the rows that meet the criteria specified in it. If the row exists only one time in your table, it doesn't matter how many times you specify you want that row in the same `WHERE` clause. The `WHERE` clause doesn't duplicate your data, rather it is a filter against the table itself.

There are a multitude of ways to accomplish duplicating your data, and the right one depends on your end goal (which you should add to your Post, right now it sounds like an XY Problem):

A. Use the natural relations of your database to create the appropriate dataset results. E.g. like mustaccio mentioned, you can `JOIN` your `items` table to the `invoices` table to create the appropriate cardinality in your results. If there are four `invoice` lines for `item 18004` then it'll show that `item`'s row four times. An example of the code for this would be:

```
SELECT Items.* 
FROM BEK_DelRio AS Items 
INNER JOIN Invoices 
    ON Items.ITEM = Invoices.ITEM 
WHERE Items.ITEM = 18004
```

B. If you want to hard-code the results cardinality instead, use the `UNION ALL` clause to multiply your data out as many times as needed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BEK_DelRio 
WHERE Items.ITEM = 18004

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM BEK_DelRio 
WHERE Items.ITEM = 18004

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM BEK_DelRio 
WHERE Items.ITEM = 18004

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM BEK_DelRio 
WHERE Items.ITEM = 18004
```

C. Another less verbose way to hard-code the cardinality can be done via `CROSS JOIN`s:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM BEK_DelRio AS A
CROSS JOIN BEK_DelRio AS B
CROSS JOIN BEK_DelRio AS C
CROSS JOIN BEK_DelRio AS D
WHERE A.ITEM = 18004
    AND B.ITEM = A.ITEM
    AND C.ITEM = A.ITEM
    AND D.ITEM = A.ITEM
```

> i guess i will duplicate my Database 5 times over to get the desired outcome

This would be the most inefficient and error prone way to do it, so I'd advise against that. You're likely looking for option A.